# Is this method of evaluating the limit of $\frac{(n!)}{(n^n)}$ correct?

Tags: limits

$\frac{(n!)}{(n^n)}$ can be written as

$\frac{(n)}{(n)} 
 \frac{(n-1)}{(n)} \frac{(n-2)}{(n)}...  
\frac{(n-(n-3))}{(n)}\frac{(n-(n-2))}{(n)} \frac{(n-(n-1))}{(n)}  $

$\frac{(1)}{(1)}\frac{(1-1/n)}{(1)} \frac{(1-2/n)}{(1)}...\frac{(1-(1-2/n))}{(1)} \frac{(1-(1-1/n))}{(1)} $

If I take the limit of $\frac{(n!)}{(n^n)}$ as n approaches infinity.

The product will evaluate to
$(1)(1)(1)...(0)(0)=0$

Comment: stirling formula

Comment: @Tsemo That works but is this method wrong ?

Comment: Amount of multipliers is dependent on $n \to \infty$, so you cannot multiply separate limits of multipliers.

Comment: @zkutch.    So that's the problem, thanks  for the correction.

Comment: There would be no factors of $0$ at any point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider an example:
$$e=e^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{\frac{1}{n}} \cdots e^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Each multiplier in right side has $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$, but the limit of the right hand side cannot be calculated as the product of the limits of the factors, since this will give $1$, while left hand is $e$.

Answer (score 2):

For infinite sum or infinite product, you can't use this type of proceed, as you see it may not work always.

You can take $\sum u_n = \sum \frac{n!}{n^n}$

As, by D'alembert test, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{1}{e} \lt 1 $

So, the series converge, hence, using necessary condition for a convergent series, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}=0$